# CATransition Cube with panning gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, catransition

I'm developing an app which displays four views above a cube which you can roll  swiping from right and from left.I've easily realized this interaction using CATransitions like this:

```
[self.view1 addSubview:nextTo1];
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:0.5];
[animation setType:@"cube"];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunctionfunctionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[[self.view1 layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"cube"];
```

Then i've hooked everything with the swipe gesture and everything works well.
The problem is that the customer is asking for a Panning gesture, so the cube rotation should follow the finger during the animation and i really don't know how to implement it without for example OpenGL (that could become much more expensive that simple transitions).
Is there a way to have more control over CATransitions or some view distortion function that i can use to solve this issue?

Thank you very much and merry Christmas!!

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is by setting `layer.speed` to zero (so that the animation doesn't move by itself),  and setting `layer.timeOffset` based on movement from your pan gesture recognizer. Setting the `timeOffset` controls the animation's progress, when `timeOffset` reaches the animation duration, it's 100% complete.

An example of this has been posted in the answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22652663/209855