# Control a UIView animation's progress manually instead of automatically through the time duration

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, core-animation

I want to setup a UIView animation, but instead of it taking a given amount of time, i want to control the percentage progress and let it automatically interpolate the values for me. Is that possible? Thanks

Comment: For animation you ultimately need to define time, thats `animation time`

Answer (score 13):

I think i've got it. Immediately after the [UIView animate...] block, do the following on the root view:

```
_view.layer.speed = 0.0;
_view.layer.timeOffset = [_view.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
```

And to set the point on the scale, do:

```
_view.layer.timeOffset = 0..1; (where 1 is the same value as the original duration)
```

And to resume, something similar to the following:

```
CALayer *layer = _view.layer;
CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer timeOffset];
layer.speed = 1.0;
layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
layer.beginTime = 0.0;
CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
```

This is all from here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1673/_index.html

Comment: This does work, but doesn't give me any way to cancel the transition in a way that its completion block still gets called.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about a simple `UIView` animation linked to some gesture recognizer, you generally would not use animation during the gesture, but rather just update the view's properties as you receive updates as the continuous gesture (e.g. `UIPanGestureRecognizer`) progresses, and then only apply a traditional animation when you let go and want complete the animation that the user initiated manually. You don't need to employ animation during the continuous gesture because those events come in quickly enough to render a smooth changing of the view's properties during the gesture. You only need traditional animation when the user lets go and you want to continue the animation smoothly to its logical conclusion.

Alternatively, if you're talking about the new iOS 7 view controller transition (a slightly complicated, very specialized scenario), you (a) set up an animator object (one that conforms to `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`); (b) set up an interaction controller (on that conforms to `UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning`, e.g. a `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`); (c) your gesture would update the interaction controller's `percentComplete`; and (d) when the gesture is done, you'd simply call either `cancelInteractiveTransition` or `finishInteractiveTransition` based upon your own logic.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that basically explains my situation perfectly. The problem is that i've had a lot of problems with the ios7 transitions, which i'm confident are caused by UIKit bugs, and also need to support ios6, so i am attempting to perform something similar.

Comment: The only view controller transition bug that I've stumbled across thus far is some strange behavior related to layout guides. But if you're supporting iOS 6, that's moot, as you'd have to achieve it via different mechanisms. If you're just swiping between view controllers, a `UIPageViewController` is an easy way (though limited in terms of the animation) to swipe between view controllers in an iOS 6 compatible manner. It just depends upon what sort of animation you're shooting for.